# Question about my reflective telescope

Tags: telescopes

So I have a Astromaster 114EQ reflective telescope my buddy has a refractor telescope a cheap one. But we were looking Jupiter through mine and it was just extremely bright without colors. But my with my friends telescope you can see the coloea. Why is this? I'm disappointed because I feel like I should have just bought a cheap refractor telescope and would have a better view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your mirror diameter is 114mm, a little over 4 inches. I don't know what your friend's objective lenses is but, I doubt that it is more than two inches. This is a topic that could result in many typed words. So let's just get to the info that matters. My bet is that you made the right choice by choosing the reflector over the refractor. 
If you want to compete with him for viewing planets, do this: Cut a 4.5" diameter circular piece of cardboard. Then cut a 2 inch diameter hole in the cardboard, not in the center but off to the side. Now put this over the front of your tube. Position the 2" hole so that a spider vane does not obstruct it. Now view the planet. This process increases the focal length of your scope. Among other things it will increase contrast. Try it; I think it will put your scope in the winner's circle. Good luck.